# How to draw something with OpenGL ES in Linux?

Tags: linux, opengl-es

I'm getting started developing with OpenGL ES on ARM/Linux, and I would like to draw something full-screen but don't know where to start.

I'm **not** developping on iPhone, nor Android. This is a Linux/OpenGL ES question.

I know it's possible to draw on the **framebuffer** with **OpenGL ES** ***without* any library** but I don't find any resources about that topic, could you help me?

---

I don't have any code to show how to do it but basicly you use de framebuffer device as the target of OpenGL|ES operations.

Answer (score 6):

Are you developing with an embedded platform as a target? If so, you could use software implementations on your host system and then the actual driver on the embedded device.

There is a small project for supporting OpenGLES 1.1 on linux called [dlges](http://dgles.sourceforge.net/). You could also try [mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/opengles.html).

I imagine that the driver itself might have a header for OpenGL that you could look at and see if it supports OpenGLES calls. Alternatively, you could set up function pointers to make your OpenGL Code look more like OpenGL ES.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that desktop Linux comes with OpenGL, not OpenGLES! They're similar but not quite compatible. If you want to do work on OpenGLES on a desktop Linux platform, ARM or otherwise, you'll need an OpenGLES emulator library. Sorry, can't recommend any, I'm looking for one myself.

OpenGLES just handles the process of drawing stuff into the window. You also need a windowing library, which handles the process of creating a window to draw stuff into, and an event library, which deals with input events coming back from the window.

SDL will provide both of the last two, as will a bunch of other libraries. Khronos themselves have standardised on EGL as the windowing library and OpenKODE as the event library... but I don't actually know where to get open source implementations of these for Linux. (I work for a company that does EGL and OpenKODE for embedded platforms, so I've never needed to find an open source version!)

Answer (score 4):

ARM offers few GPUs that support OpenGL 2.0. You can find some examples and and emulator that runs on linux on the [Mali Developer](http://www.malideveloper.com/developer-resources/tools/index.php) site.
Of course that's mostly to target ARM GPUs, but I am pretty sure it could be used to examine OpenGL ES programming possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://pandorawiki.org/OpenGL_ES_1.1_Tutorial) is a tutorial showing how to use [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) in combination with OpenGL ES. It's for the [OpenPandora](http://openpandora.org/) platform, but since that runs Linux, it should be applicable on the desktop if you can get the proper library versions.

Use of SDL is more or less standard with this kind of programming, in Linux. You can of course go the longer route and open the window yourself, attach a GL rendering context and so on, but usually it's easier to learn the relevant parts of SDL. That also gives you easy-to-use API:s for input reading, which is almost always necessary.

Comment: I don't want to use any library just plain OpenGL ES implementation for linux and framebuffer device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerVR SDK for Linux http://community.imgtec.com/developers/powervr/graphics-sdk/
There are a lot of samples.